# Validating input text field, do not accept first character as a number and special character

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input-field

#### Allow valid case and prevent invalid case in Input text field

The input field must accept the following:

**Valid cases**
`qw12@`
`qwe12`
`qweryt@123`

And not accept the following:

**Invalid case**
`1a@`
`@qwe1`
`1@qwer`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that making you textInput a controlled component

```js
const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = useState('')

  const onTextInputChange = (newText) => {
    //Here you can manipulate the value of the textinput as you want

    setTextInputValue(newText)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} value={textInputValue} onChangeText={onTextInputChange} />
    </View>
  );
```

consider that with this solution you might experience some flickering issues if the user type faster than react-native is able to update the native view.

Otherwise you can try to implement it natively, for instance [here's](https://github.com/fbeccaceci/react-native-regex-text-input) an example of a custom wrapper for the TextInput component which allows to pass a regex to whitelist allowed characters